# Typing comment notes within the GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, comments

To comment out a note in Code Behind, I can do this:

```
' This is my VB comment
/// This is my C# comment
```

In my .aspx page, I can use the following:

```
 <!-- I'm commenting on my .aspx page -->
```

as long as it is not within my

```
<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>
```

This gives me an error stating that Literal content is not allowed:

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Scheduled_Pick" HeaderText="Max_Scheduled_Pick" SortExpression="Max_Scheduled_Pick" DataFormatString="{0:MMM dd yyyy}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <!-- These are the Order Notes -->
        <asp:BoundField DataField="txt_Order_Key" HeaderText="txt_Order_Key" SortExpression="txt_Order_Key" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
```

Any suggestions on how to add comments into my code for documentation purposes?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using ASP comments:

```
<%-- --%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dang! Sometimes you just have to ask the question in a different way to get your answer. I found it: my comments need to be like this:

```
<%-- These are the Order Notes --%>
```